# Time Complexity of the C program

Tags: c, time-complexity

What will be the time complexity of the following function?
is it O(n^3) or O(n^4)?

i am getting O(n^3)
in the first `for` loop, it will undergo n times.
in the second `for`loop, for every nth element it will go n^2 times, therefore the total complexity till here is O(n^3)
now, the `if` statement will only hold true value only for n out of n^2 values, and for every n values the k- `for` loop will go till n^2 elements and hence the complexity is O(n^3).
I have taken few values of n:
for n=3 ,c=25

for n=10,c=1705

for n=50,c=834275

```
for(i=1;i<=n;++i)                            
    for(j=1;j<=(i*i);++j)  
        if((j%i)==0)                               
            for(k=1;k<=j;++k)      
                c=c+1;
```

Comment: Its of order O(n^4). For `i = n`, second loop will run `n^2` times and for `j = i*i` third loop will run `n^2` times.

Comment: You want us to do your excersize instead of you?

Comment: @haccks can you please explain how??

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity of such program is `O(n^3)` magnitude.

Comment: You you care to add some explanation? As it is your answer is not very useful. You need you justify your answer.